# How to mask animated objects so they aren't visible past a certain area?

Tags: node-editor, video, masking

I am animating objects that will be rendered with video footage in the compositor. My difficulty is how to apply a mask so that the objects disappear when they expand past a certain point.

Objects within circle mesh should be visible
[image]

Objects outside of circle mesh should be invisible
[image]

Current nodes set-up for object materials:
[image]

What masking options are at my disposal to achieve this effect, and how can I apply them?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-use-an-object-as-a-mask and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/best-practices-for-masking-image-layers-for-compositing and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7613/create-invisibility-cloak-alpha-mask-material

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a good many ways of doing this, but here are a few:

## Mask editor

1. In the *UV image editor*, set the mode to *Mask* and press *New*:

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*>Circle* to add a circle mask, the position it with <kbd>G</kbd>:

   [image]
3. Use the mask to control the alpha over factor in the compositor:

   [image]

   You could even feather or blur the mask to make the objects fade out instead of disappearing abruptly.

## Object/material id mask

You could also use the circle object in the 3D view to do this, using ID masks (see my [answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3099/599)).

Note that this will only work if you have the circle object visible in the render and filled with a face, or use multiple renderlayers.

## Holdout material:

If you want to replace part of a scene with transparency, you can use an object with a holdout shader to make that object render as alpha transparency:

[image]

## Boolean modifier

This is probably not a good option in this case, but this can be useful when you need to "mask" whole objects:

[image]

## Collision object

If the object is in a particle system, you can use a sphere with collision physics, set to kill particles:

[image]

No particles will be able to escape the sphere.

Comment: Is there a way to do the reverse (inverse?) of this? Everything inside the circle needs to be visible; everything outside needs to be invisible.

Comment: @KTS Ah, I misunderstood. Simply remove the invert node in the compositing setup.