# How to make metaballs particles appear only inside an object?

Tags: particles, meta-objects

I need to have a particle system with metaballs that floats around but appear only inside an object, like if I was using an boolean intersect modifier, are there any other way?

Comment: If someone manages to look at the center of a spherical particle that is cut in half by a invisible wall, I think they would be very innovative. It's a tricky combination of features and I don't think that can be easily achieved. But there are a number of ways objects or particles can be made to disappear.

I propose you start scrolling down to **Collision object** here:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/how-to-mask-animated-objects-so-they-arent-visible-past-a-certain-area?rq=1

Comment: I know it'spossible in cinema4D but i'd rather not learn a new program just for this