How to create rim light effect with compositor?
The video in the link shows rim light effect and a few related nodes, but I couldn't figure out how to create it. How can I create such an effect using Compositor?
https://x.com/homspau/status/1817637789493862534


I don't see any magic trick : mask the area and shade it. It's either you doing it manually in compositing, or in lighting automatically.

@Lutzi can you show how to do it manually in compositing like in the video?

That's just a mask and change the color to achieve the look you seek. Old but still relevant I think : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/best-practices-for-masking-image-layers-for-compositing

@Lutzi this does not answer my question

Then what's the issue exactly ? How to create a mask ? How to animate it ? How to use it in compositor ? How to change the color towards a bright orange ? Something else ?

@Lutzi I don't think the rim light effect in the video has anything to do with 2D masks, if you think so, please make the effect in the video using a 2D mask and rotate the rim light effect by changing only 1 parameter

I agree, this isn't done in compositing in my opinion. I don't understand why you would do that in compositing, it would be a pain. Maybe someone has a better idea than masks.

@Lutzi The link says it is done in Blender's 4.3 "multipass viewport compositor", so it is done in compositing. The problem is, the video only shows it is done with a custom nodegroup called "Normal Mask" where it seems you can set a rotation angle for the rim light. But how it is done exactly and if it is something that necessarily has to be done in 4.3 is not clear. At least I cannot see any explanations or comments on that (but maybe just because I'm no registered user there).

@GordonBrinkmann I don't think the fact he/she uses compositing means that the rim light is purely done in compositing. Maybe the rim light is rendered in its own layer, in this case there is not much compositing in the process, it's done by lighting. I don't know.
